# Sniffing packets on localhost with Scapy

Tags: scapy, packet-sniffers

I'm learning how to use [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) to sniff packets. I have set up a simple echo server running on localhost on port 50420.

I then enter the following line in my terminal to sniff for packets on that port when I send traffic over it:

```
p = sniff(filter = 'port 50420')
```

However, no packets are captured, although the data flowed correctly. I have verified that sniffing works for other traffic not using localhost. How can I sniff this localhost traffic using Scapy, if at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that line you are sniffing the traffic over the port 50420, but you should do something more. You should add one function to jump when you sniff the packets

```
sniff(filter="port 50420",prn=myFunction)
```

And write myFunction:

```
def myFunction(pkt):
    print "Packet!"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to specify the interface.  In Linux,

```
    sniff(filter="port 50420",iface="lo")
```

Of course to use the packets, you will need to either specify a callback function with "prn" option (as mentioned in an other response) or you can save the packets to a list for later use, e.g.

```
    packet_list = sniff(filter="port 50420",iface="lo")
    first_packet = packet_list[0]
```

To make extra sure, you can set the filter to something like "port 50420 and host 127.0.0.1"