# Scapy don't listen another port

Tags: python, port, scapy

I have server running on port 5555 and I use the client to send to server I want use scapy to
read package from client send to server

This is the file server.py

```
import socket
import pickle
# Create a server socket
serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serverAddress = ('', 5555)
serverSocket.bind(serverAddress)
serverSocket.listen(1)
print('Listening for incoming connections...')

while True:
  clientSocket, clientAddress = serverSocket.accept()
  print('Client connected:', clientAddress)
  receivedData = clientSocket.recv(1024)
  print('Received country names:')
  print(receivedData)
```

this is response:

```
Client disconnected: ('127.0.0.1', 53944)
Client connected: ('127.0.0.1', 54713)
Received country names:
country_list
```

and this working bellow is file client.py:

```
import socket
import pickle
host = 'localhost'  # Use 'localhost' if running the server locally
port = 5555         # Port of the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
country_list = "country_list"
data = pickle.dumps(country_list)
s.sendall(data)
print("send data success:", data)
s.close()
```

this is response:

```
send data success: b'\x80\x04\x95\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x0ccountry_list\x94.'
```

this also working but file between.py not working:
from scapy.all import *

```
# Define the callback function to process captured packets

print("Start")
def packet_handler(packet):
  print(packet)
  if packet.haslayer(TCP) and packet[TCP].dport == 5555:
     # Print the packet information to the console
     print(packet.summary())
sniff(filter="dst port 5555", prn=packet_handler, store=0)
```

but file between is nothing

Comment: I suspect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28667985/sniffing-packets-on-localhost-with-scapy answers your question.  I'm not closing this as a duplicate just in case it doesn't.

Comment: sorry but this not is my sol is have func to handle @FrankYellin

Comment: No, but it also explains why you're not seeing packets for localhost: